# Слетела кодировка в одной папке флешки

Tags: кодировка

Слетела кодировка на флешке, но только в одной папке. Возможно ли восстановить файлы? Все остальные файлы в порядке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]